# How to set height and width for Relative Layout through code

Tags: android

I want to add one imageView, TextView in a Relative Layout with background image through programmatically.I spedified height and width for the relative layout but it is not fitting to the specified width and height. where am going wrong ploesae help 
Thanks in advance
here is my Code:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_topheader = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(800,45);
    relative_topheader = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relative_topheader.setLayoutParams(lp_topheader);
    relative_topheader.setId(1);
    Resources resources_topheader = getResources();
    Drawable drawable_topheader = resources_topheader.getDrawable(R.drawable.headerbar_m);
    relative_topheader.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable_topheader);
    setContentView(relative_topheader);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp_banner = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(385, 206);
    relative_banner = new RelativeLayout(this);
    relative_banner.setId(2);
    relative_banner.setLayoutParams(lp_banner);
    lp_banner.setMargins(40, 40, 0, 0);
    lp_banner.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
    ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);         
    iv.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY);
    iv.setLayoutParams(lp_banner);
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.banner_image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    setContentView(iv, lp_banner);
```

Comment: first create complete layout and then set it to setcontentView().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root view (that is, the view that you set as the content view) always fill the entire area of the window. If you want it to take only a certain part, add it to another Layout that will take the entire window.

Try this instead of the last line:

```
LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
ll.addView(iv, lp_banner);
setContentView(ll);
```

Comment: will you please explain it with a sample

Comment: -@Rotem the above given code(My code) works but only the second layout is displayed in emulator this my second problem.

Comment: if you want them both to be displayed then you should also add the first layout to ll. when you call setContentView() it resets all the previous setContentView calls.

Comment: okey i unbderstood and how to implement this in it because first time am creating layouts and its views through code so i need help please..